# Need to import a RDS file from my desktop using readRDS. What would the exact code for this be?

Tags: r

lets say the files name is abcd and location is 'C:\Users\mrX\Desktop'

what would the readRDS for this function exactly look like? So that I can import data from the file 'abcd' to R.

Answer (score 0):

The `readRDS` function can be called with the path to the `.rd` file as a string and assigned to a variable in your working environment:

```
data <- readRDS("C:/Users/mrX/Desktop/abcd.rds")
```